# Invalid Syntax - Pyflakes Error in try except statement - repl.it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, try-except, pyflakes

My code:

````
elif message.content.startswith(";random-number"):
channel = client.get_channel(1004728545911787740)
await channel.send("**Command received:** " + str(message.content) + "\n ```" + str(message) + "```")
try:
  range = int(message.content.replace(";random-number ", "")
  await message.channel.send("Random number: " + random.randint(0, int(range)))
except:
  await message.channel.send(random.choice(["Use the command like this: ", "Here is how you can use the command: "]))
  await message.channel.send("`;random-number [max number]`\nExample:\nUser - `;random-number 100`\nCorion - Random number: 67")
````

When I run my code I get this error:

```
File "main.py", line 150
    await message.channel.send("Random number: " + random.randint(0, int(range)))
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It seems there a syntax problem at this line:
[image]

I can't really understand where the syntax error is though. I also tried str-ing the random.randint(0,int(range) but it doesn't work either. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: your `elif` statement is empty (first line) and will cause syntax errors.

Comment: `await` can only be used inside an `async` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax issue is the line above

```
range = int(message.content.replace(";random-number ", "")
```

You are missing the closing brace

```
range = int(message.content.replace(";random-number ", ""))
```

Comment: It's better to comment and vote to close/flag a typo question than to answer it.

Comment: Usually i would agree, but as the majority of comments led a lot of people to look at the "await" line , i believed my answer would be useful for wider audiences.